# Two or more different text messages in the same panel of a lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice

Given the following example of a lattice plot with an artificial dataset:

```
library(lattice)
set.seed(120)
X<-rnorm(100)
Y<-rnorm(100)
Z<-c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))
df1<-data.frame(X,Y,Z)

myx <- c(1,-1)
myy <- c(0,0)
MyText<-c("Panel 1 Text", "Panel 2 Text")

xyplot(X~Y|Z, data=df1,
panel=function(x, y,...){
panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
panel.text(myx[panel.number()],myy[panel.number()]
,labels=MyText[panel.number()])})
```

This is the plot:[image]

I would like to have 'Panel 1 Text' and 'Panel 2 Text' in the same panel, say it the first panel for example. Please note that the real problem has many panels and I want to place sometimes text twice in one panel and have it once in other panels.

Could anyone help me on that please ?

Comment: use `panel.number()` to select the panel ... `panel.number()==1`

Comment: yes but this way I have to define different vectors `myx` `myy` and `Mytext` for each panel number that has two texts in a single panel. Thus many vectors around, isn't there a way to index the vector just as we can index `panel.number()`